# Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

What is happening in this code http://ideone.com/stD7VU

First I thought ok i'm using an int for a pointer and the compiler doesn't warn me. Then the 2nd block I can't understand how I can dereference `a` when I didnt use `new`. Whats happening? I don't know obj-c.

```
#import <stdio.h>

@implementation TestObj
int main()
{
    {
        int *a;
        a=5;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    {
        int *a;
        *a=7;
        printf("%d\n", *a);
    }
    return 0;
}
@end
```

Comment: WTH is `main()` enclosed in an `@implementation`!? Read a beginner C tutorial... (and you will find out that 1. you can **not** dereference `a`, and 2. `new` is not C but C++.)

Comment: @H2CO3: ideone puts it in there as their template code. The main body was all me (but not return 0). I do know C which is why I went WTF when I didnt get a runtime error/segfault. Are you saying the 2nd block is completely illegal?

Comment: “I went WTF when I didnt get a runtime error/segfault.”  Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior means your program can do anything: it can silently do nothing, or it can seg fault, or it can erase your hard drive, or it can shoot your dog.  So stay away from undefined behavior.

Comment: @robmayoff: I'll accept that as an answer. I caught a bit of the deleted answer and it mentioned the compiler does warn me but ideone site doesnt show it unless maybe theres a compile error. I'll ask this as a side question. Does obj-c have anything like a C++ reference? or some kind of pointer I don't need to free and can be null?

Comment: In Objective-C the only pointers you don't have to manually allocate/deallocate are object pointers, i.e. pointers to the `struct objc_object` type. Those pointers, in ARC, are automatically initialized to `nil` (a sort of Objective-C equivalent of `nil`) and automatically freed when the object's retain count reaches 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First I thought ok i'm using an int for a pointer and the compiler doesn't warn me.

Actually it does. In the first block, the line

```
a=5;
```

will rise a compiler warning, specifically

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning 'int *' from 'int'.

---

> I can't understand how I can dereference a when I didnt use new

You are trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer. This is undefined behavior in C (and being Objective-C a superset of C, so it's in it), so you program could technically print the whole Divine Comedy by Dante and still be consistent with the specification.

By the way you don't need any special C construct  for initializing pointers. Objective-C is a proper subset of C, so you can use `malloc`.

In case of objects there's a whole set of APIs dedicated to object allocation and deallocation, including `new`.

Comment: Theres nothing in my question that says I don't know C. My entire question is why does this seem to work. I know that I shouldn't be able to dereference `a` and said that. Anyways I said `new` because I don't know what the obj-c equivalent is. At the moment your answer is not helpful. You didn't say if this code was legal or not and you haven't explain a thing. This should have been a comment. I'd DV if i could

Comment: I finally - I think - got your question. Here's an updated version of the answer.

Comment: I see, I guess ideone doesn't print warnings unless there is a compiler error. So it's undefined behavior. That makes sense. +1 and Accepted.